# How to manage multiple indexes to same data?

Tags: python, dictionary, indexing

I am writing python code and I have a certain bit of data that needs to be accesses in multiple ways.
I can't publish the exact example, but here's the analog.  So in pseudo code, I have a pod of:

```
int floorid   # which factory floor
int robotid   # which robot arm on the floor
int partnum   # what part is being mfg'ed.
[...]         # other sorts of data regarding statistics.
```

This data will be coming in at regular intervals.  At any one time, floorid/robotid can be making a part.  And only one part is made at any one time.  Depending on the user, they may want to naturally index this by floorid/robotid (say a maintenance worker), or by partnum (perhaps a parts manager.)

The question is, what's the best way to provide multiple views of the same data?  I thought I could make two dictionaries that point to the same data.  So something like

```
floorid = datum.floorid
robotid = datum.robotid
partnum = datum.partnum

maintenance[floorid][robotid] = datum
supplychain[partnum] = datum
```

Is this the way to go?  I would have to do this each time I get a new datum.  There will be alot of data, and I don't want to reconstruct one 'view', off another.  I'm just looking for other ideas.  Thanks.

Comment: Yet this is *exactly* what databases *do*; you tell it to create indexes and the database keeps them updated with all the data changes you make. Perhaps you wanted to use a database instead? `sqlite3` is included out-of-the-box.

Comment: The only 'trick' that databases employ is encapsulation. Updating indexes is part of the system; the outside world is presented with a clearly defined API (SQL) and as you use the API to add or remove or change data, the database will keep the indices in sync.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I think if I were to present this idea that we need to use a database, the architects and system engineers will flip.  I don't have a say on that matter, as much as I like.  I guess I will edit my original post for a purely pythonic solution, if everyone suggests I go dB.  But, I will definitely keep your suggestion in mind.

Comment: If you use `sqlite3` using the in-memory database connection, there is *nothing external* to your script. All you get is a database architecture without having to install additional servers or having employ a full-on DBA.

Comment: Okay.  sqlite3 in-memory looks like a good way to go.  I could possibly sell this, but I'll have to do some research on it.  Part of the problem is all this python code is suppose to run inside hw with 'limited' foot print.  If I start talking about how we need to add a in-memory database, the people who are in charge of what packages get installed on the hw will have a cow.  I don't feel like fighting that battle when to them the problem is 'easy'.  Anyways, thanks a million for this suggestion, I still look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Martijn-Pieters has already pointed out in the comments this does sound a lot like a job for a database. You can run sqlite3 very simply in python and either maintain the data in a single file or keep it in memory if you don't care about losing it.

Having said that if you wanted to do it in python you might do something like:

```
import collections

raw_data = []
idx_maintenance = collections.defaultdict(set)
idx_supplychain = collections.defaultdict(set)

Datum = collections.namedtuple('Datum', 'floorid robotid partnum')

def add_data(floorid, robotid, partnum):
    datum = Datum(floorid, robotid, partnum)
    raw_data.append(datum)

    idx_maintenance[(floorid, robotid)].add(datum)
    idx_supplychain[partnum].add(datum)
    # whatever other indexes you need

# so you can add stuff
add_data(1, 1, 1)
add_data(1, 1, 2)
add_data(1, 1, 3)
add_data(1, 2, 1)

# then you can use the indexes to do lookups
set_of_data = idx_maintenance[(1, 1)]
```

This is assuming that you could have multiple partnums per (floorid, robotid) etc.

Honestly though. You really sound like you want a database.

Now an example using sqlite3:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')

c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE datum (floorid int, robotid int, partnum int)''')
conn.commit()

c = conn.cursor()
new_data = [(1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 3), (1, 2, 1)]
c.executemany('INSERT INTO datum VALUES (?,?,?)', new_data)
conn.commit()

# exercise for the reader - add indexes

c = conn.cursor()
for row in c.execute('SELECT * FROM datum WHERE floorid=? and robotid=?', (1, 1)):
    print(row)
```

Don't even tell the architects there's a database hidden in there. They'll never know the difference :)

Either way, wrap the details in a class / module out of site and access it using `mydatastore.add_record(whatever)`, `mydatastore.records_matching(robotid=1, ...)` etc then you can always change the data storage mechanism later.

I'd wager if you write it yourself that point will be when you realise that you've accidentally screwed up your data by not removing something from one of the indexes when it's removed from the datastore or something and you remember why it is that databases are your best friend when it comes to storing and indexing data :)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to post this nicely presentable answer.  A question about he pure python solution.  If we add index twice, are we duplicating datum?  Also, is it possible to update one index  say floorid, and robotid, and have the same data be 'updated' when indexing by partnum?  It's something you can do with C/C++ (having the two indexes point to the same place in memory), but I don't know enough about python to know if it can be done here too.

Comment: Ah, yeah, we're duplicating it here. So, is partnum unique to a single entity? And it's alway allocated to a floor/robot combination? That is to say, I couldn't have 2 partnums (both of value 1234) in different locations. partnum 1234 is a single 'thing' to be shuffled around?

Comment: Yeah.  Meaning, a given partnum can only be made on a single robot assembly.  You won't have two robot arms making the same part at the same time.

Comment: Ok. So that's a bit more interesting. I haven't quite thought that through yet but it implies that partnum is the one true key that everything else should be based off. The other ids, eg robotid are really `facts` about partnum. Having said that, maybe robotid, floorid is the key? But presumably robotid is also unique? You would have robotid 1 on floorid 1 and floorid 2. Also, does a robot changes floors?

Comment: It feels like you have 2 datasets (robot, floor) - which doesn't really change. And (robot, partnum) which changes as the robot changes task. If that's right then you'd design around those constraints. Are my assumptions correct? Is there other data concerned?

Comment: Hello Aidan.  Thanks again.  They really are two ways to view the same data.  There can be 5 floors, and 8 robots on each floor, each robot numbered 0-7.  At some point, one floor/robot id can be working on a part.  At another time, the part may be 'moved' to another floor/robot.  So a manager concerned with supply chain management, may just be concerned  at looking at the data from a 'partnum' point of view.  But, somebody else, say a maintenance engineer maybe want to know how a particular floor/robot is doing.  Both stake holders will be looking at the rest of the data in '[...]'.

Comment: Ok. And the statistics in [...], they pertain to the robot, or the partnum? Just trying to get a picture of how you'd be doing the updating.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63049/discussion-between-bitdiot-and-aidan-kane).